# Plural of "Coke Zero" as a drink

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I am wondering:

Instead of saying: "I would like to have/drink 2 glasses/bottles of Coke zero/light", what would be the plural form of the more colloquial rendering?:

I will drink 2 Coke zeros

or

I will drink two Cokes zero?

Same with "light"? --> two Cokes light / two Coke lights?

Or are both forms in use actually?

Comment: Only the Coca Cola Company can tell you their official way of saying it.

Comment: Note that ‘X light’ is more commonly called ‘diet X’ in English.

Answer (score 2):

I did Google searches for "drink cokes zero" and "drink coke zeros". The former ("drink cokes zero") came up with 0 results (one false positive). On the other hand "drink coke zeros" came up with several results (~15), such as [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/keto/comments/6evfea/are_coke_zeros_ok/) and this [CityGuide article](http://www.chiangmaicitylife.com/citylife-articles/cityguide-sansai/). (It's also worth noting that the Reddit link also has an example of someone calling them "Zeroes", with an *e*.)

Thus, due to the clear discrepancy in use (and also how weird "Cokes Zero" sounds), the correct version is "Coke Zeros". The same should be true for Coke Light.

Comment: Thank you very much. My research and sense of fluency also came to the same result, but I was just not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that *Zero* does not modify *Coke* in this case as you might have interpreted it ("*Cokes Zero*"); *Coke Zero* is a proper noun, and plural is formed by adding an *-s*.

So, the plural would simply be, for example, *I ordered **2 Coke Zeros***